# Moving lemma on Abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $Y,Z$ be two cycles on a quasi-projective manifold $X$, Chow's moving lemma says there is a cycle $Z'$ rationally equivalent to $Z$ such that $Y,Z'$ intersect properly.

Suppose $X$ is an Abelian variety, is there an explicit way to find such a $Z'$?
(Kleiman's moving lemma allows us to find $Z'$ such that it intersects properly with $Y$, but moving by auotmorphism of Abelian variety may not be(or must not be?) rational equivalence.)

Comment: Translations $\tau_a$ work well for divisors by the Theorem of the Square: $2\tau_a^* Z - \tau_{2a}^*Z$ is linearly equivalent to $Z$, and it is easy to arrange a choice of $a$ so that it meet $Y$ properly. For higher codimension it is not as neat, and it depends on what is meant by "explicit," but in practice, couldn't we reduce to the codimension one case? Assuming WLOG $Z$ an irreducible subscheme, write it as a component of an intersection of hypersurfaces, then apply the preceding to one of those hypersurfaces, etc.